# Activity's finish() doesn't work and second onCreate is called

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, android-dialogfragment

I have a Main Activity that calls Activity_View_Turn

`intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity_View_Turn.class);`
`startActivityForResult(intent, RC_VIEW_TURN);`

A dialogFragment is displayed from Activity_view_Turn.

`fragdialog_view_summary newFragment = new fragdialog_view_summary().newInstance();`
`newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");`

In the dialogFragment there is an interface implemented by the Activity_View_Turn which executes this

`Intent returnIntent = new Intent();`
`setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);`
`finish();`

In about 1 of 10 times, the onCreate of Activity_view_Turn will execute (a second time) after the onPause() is triggered by finish().  The onPause() only has the `super.onPause()`

If I try and finish() again the onActivityResult() in the Main Activity will then get executed twice.  The first Result however, doesn't get pushed to the onActivityResult() until after the second finish();

Comment: Is `onCreate()` being called twice on the same instance? Or is a new instance of the `Activity` created and then `onCreate()` is called on that instance?

Comment: Generally what you've described makes no sense at all. There's something very strange happening.

Comment: @DavidWasser I don't believe the onCreate is being called by a second instance.  Unless it can exit without calling onActivityResult in the Main_Activity.   The Activity_View_Turn does have a surfaceview which is updated via its run() method until X amount of updates are completed.  I didn't know if that was complicating the finish() of the Activity_VIew_Turn.

Comment: Add logging to `onCreate()` and output the value of `this`, which is the object ID. If it is different each time `onCreate()` is called, then they are different instances. I highly doubt that `onCreate()` is being called more than once on a single instance.

Comment: Adding this line to the Activity_View_Turn onCreate()
```Log.d(TAG, "Activity View ID " + String.valueOf(this.hashCode()));```
Got this result when the Error Occured:

2019-11-28 13:55:18.489 : Activity View ID 182823724
**************************
2019-11-28 13:55:28.948 : Activity View ID 107750691

The first being the original start and the second after finish() was executed

Comment: Are you going through an orientation change? That would cause the `Activity` to be destroyed and a new instance to be created. I'm having a hard time following what you are doing.

Comment: In any case, Android is definitely creating a new instance of the `Activity`, as you can see from the different object IDs in your logging

Comment: @DavidWasser I think that might be my problem.  On my test device, I was restricting orientation change within Android's settings, but I would get the icon at the bottom showing an orientation change was detected.  When I rotate I can  reproduce the issue, so I will handle the orientation change and see if the issue goes away.  Thank you for your time and insight!!